# In Neo4j Graph Data Science, can I create graph by cypher with custom type name?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I create graph from tag nodes, where the relationships in the created graph are not relationships from original database, but some paths which represent tags are tagged on the same videos.

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher(
  "tags",
  "MATCH (t:Tag) RETURN id(t) AS id, labels(t) AS labels",
  "
  MATCH (t:Tag)
  WITH collect(t) as nodes
  UNWIND nodes as n
  UNWIND nodes as m
  WITH n, m WHERE id(n) < id(m)
  MATCH (n)-[:TAGGED_ON]->(v:Video)<-[:TAGGED_ON]-(m)
  RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, count(v) AS weight
  "
)
```

And then I do this to export to new database:

```
CALL gds.graph.export("tags", {dbName: "tags"})

CREATE DATABASE tags
```

However, the relationships in the new tags database will all named `__ALL__`.

In the relationshipQuery part of graph creation, docs of neo4j say

> Optionally, a type column can be specified to represent relationship type.

However, all examples I found about this are `type(r) AS type`, where this cannot work on my case. I still can rename the relationships in the new tags database by this:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
WITH collect(r) AS rels
CALL apoc.refactor.rename.type("__ALL__", "TAGGED_ON_THE_SAME_VIDEO", rels)
YIELD committedOperations
RETURN committedOperations
```

But can I use the custom relationship name at the gds graph creation time? I tried something like `"TAGGED_ON_THE_SAME_VIDEO" AS type` but this cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried something like "TAGGED_ON_THE_SAME_VIDEO" AS type but this
> cannot work.

Why this cannot work? I've tested it and it works just fine. Try the following query to project the graph:

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher(
  "tags",
  "MATCH (t:Tag) RETURN id(t) AS id, labels(t) AS labels",
  "
  MATCH (t:Tag)
  WITH collect(t) as nodes
  UNWIND nodes as n
  UNWIND nodes as m
  WITH n, m WHERE id(n) < id(m)
  MATCH (n)-[:TAGGED_ON]->(v:Video)<-[:TAGGED_ON]-(m)
  RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, count(v) AS weight, 'TAGGED_ON_THE_SAME_VIDEO' as type
  "
)
```

Comment: Ouch, I got it. A stupid error, I forget change "" to '' inside "" string... thx!